# Php login hide when logged in and hide logout when not logged in

Tags: php, authentication

I want a code to hide login button when logged in and display "welcome,username" and the logout button and when not logged in to display the login button... 
http://needforgaming.x10.mx/testefinal/home.html This is my website you can see how it looks idk if it is where i put the code thaths wrong or the code

```
<?php 
             session_start();
            if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
    <p>Ola; <u><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></u>, </p>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
<?php } else{ ?>
    <p><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: idk where problem is... the point is hide the login button if user loged in what isnt working... bought buttons keep appearing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another easy method. You can start session firstly. Then use this code:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        echo '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

actually this code is for using login/logout in . You can use it where ever you need. Just change the html tags. That's it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using **plain** `html` .. your page needs to be of `php` to run this code on a apache/IIS server, code is good enough to work.

Comment: Well thath worked out pretty fine but im having 1 error thath idk why now Prints this : Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/needforg/public_html/testefinal/home.php:80) in /home/needforg/public_html/testefinal/home.php on line 81

Comment: put session  `<?php session_start() ?>` on first line of your page and remove it if it's declared anywhere else on page

Comment: @TonySantos put the `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the very first line of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check for emptiness. Change:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
```

to

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put PHP code to `.html` page. Either switch it to `.php`, or configure your server to evaluate `.html` as PHP too.

Take a look at [Your first PHP-enabled page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php), it should provide sufficient details.

Answer (score 0):

you should make all the block a php code:

```
<?php 
     session_start();
     if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
     echo "<p>Ola; <u> $_SESSION['username']; </u>, </p>";
     echo "<p><a href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></p>";
     } else{
      echo" <p><a href=\"#login-box\" class=\"login-window\">Login</a></p>";
     }
```

?>